# Cran-R BatchGetSymbols: What are fetch limitations, how to keep quiet and can I pass a vector of dates?

Tags: r, yahoo-api

I am using Cran-R's BatchGetSymbols function to download data from Yahoo. What are the current download limitations? There are docs on Stack Overflow related to Yahoo, (not BatchGetSymbols), but they seem old. Also is there away to keep the function from outputting so much text each time it runs? I.e. make it quiet? Is it possible to pass a vector of dates? I have about 3000 symbols I need, each with a different date range. Currently, I call it separately for each symbol because the dates are different, so each time the function is called, it prints messages, which is getting annoying. It would be a lot more efficient if I could call the function once with a 2 vector of dates (one for start and one for end) and a vector of symbols.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
library(dplyr)
library("rvest")
url <- "https://www.bseindia.com/markets/equity/EQReports/MarketWatch.aspx"
data <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)

df <- data[[9]]

df <- df[, -c(11:21)]
```

Or, you can take things further, and get returns (you can do all kinds of other things in addition to this).

```
library(timeSeries)
library(fPortfolio)
library(quantmod)
library(caTools)
library(dplyr)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(ggplot2)
library(BatchGetSymbols)
library(tidyr)
library(quantmod)

# set dates
first.date <- Sys.Date() - 360
last.date <- Sys.Date()

# set tickers
tickers <- c('MMM','ABT','ABBV','ABMD',
             'ACN','ATVI','AYI','ADBE','AMD','AAP')

out <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = tickers, 
                       first.date = first.date,
                       last.date = last.date, 
                       cache.folder = file.path(tempdir(), 
                                                'BGS_Cache') ) 
out<-out$df.tickers
out<-out[,c("ref.date","ticker", "price.adjusted")]
q <- spread(out, ticker, price.adjusted)
portfolioPrices <- xts(q[,-1], order.by=q[,1])


out<-out$df.tickers
out<-out[,c("ref.date","ticker", "price.adjusted")]


# Eliminate Dupes
deduped_data <- unique( out[ , 1:3 ] )


q <- spread(deduped_data, ticker, price.adjusted)
portfolioPrices <- xts(q[,-1], order.by=q[,1])


#Rename Columns
colnames(portfolioPrices) <- tickers

#Calculate Returns: Daily RoC
portfolioReturns <- na.omit(ROC(portfolioPrices, type="discrete"))
portfolioReturns <- as.timeSeries(portfolioReturns)
```

I believe the Yahoo API was turned off around 2 years ago.